# Is MPI using a thread pool?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmp, threadpool

I know OpenMP uses a thread pool and threads are created when needed and go to sleep at 'Join'.

Is MPI using a thread pool?

Comment: MPI uses processes. Otherwise it could never run across a network. You can not do that with threads.

Comment: FWIW, and though this is not mandated by the MPI standard strictly speaking, most implementations start all the process at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPI uses processes. Otherwise it could never run across a network. You can not do that with threads.